# 3rd Normal Form in Database

Tags: sql, database

Third Normal Form – the table is in second normal form and all of its columns are not transitively dependent on the primary key. I want to know what is meant by transitively dependent. Can somebody explain it with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a relation `R(A,B,C)` and functional dependencies `A->B`, `B->C` then `C` is transitively dependent on `A`.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate it by giving an example of small table with some columns?

Comment: @robot here: https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/third-normal-form-3nf.php you can find a nice example

Comment: @robot By the way it is not nice to change the question goals when there are already answers (it can generate downvotes). Use word EDIT in your question and add new requirements there.

Comment: @Radam Bača Thanks